# Js how can I delete message with a selfbot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Ii want to send a message every 1min (this is ok)
but I want to delete the message instantly after he sent (I need help for that)

I tried some things but it doesn't work

```
//THIS CODE IS RIGHT 
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = "**************************************";

client.login(token);

client.on('ready', () => {

    var testecrit = client.channels.find(channel => channel.id === 
'592118296770510893');

    console.log("Je suis pret patron");

    setInterval(() => {
        testecrit.send("le test de l envoi est concluant.");  
    },5000);
});
```

So what will be the code that I need to add to my existing code, to delete the message sent instantly ?

Comment: Self bots are against Discord's terms of services.

Answer (score 0):

Selfbots are against Discord Terms of Service. You can get your account deleted for this. I would recommend you to use a bot account instead of a user account.